# How to use image source from tmp folder of ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, path, file-location

I have a jsp web application running on Ubuntu apache server. I take screen shot of different picture and save those in tmp folder of the server. Now I need to show this picture in my web application. How can I show picture in my application from tmp folder?

when I set image source src="/tmp/zzz.png" is not working.

Comment: You need to make `/tmp` accessible to apache. Is saving the screenshot somewhere else an option?

Comment: Is there any way to move this picture from tmp folder to my web application folder programmtically?

Comment: Can't you chose where the screenshot is saved?

Comment: yes , I can choose the location like I could save my location like /var/lib/tomcat6/data/images folder but when I save /var/lib/tomcat6/data/images in this location it did not saved. I dont know the problem but I can save in /tmp/ folder.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if its the correct way of doing this but it works.

You simply make a symbolic link

```
ln -S /tmp /your/project/directory
```

for the /tmp directory inside your project and you can use it like a normal image inside a directory.

Hope this helps